# Shared preferences + Scrollable slider

Tags: android, if-statement, sharedpreferences, viewflipper

UPDATED

I am having a troublesome and tricky activity where:
-IF it is the first time the app is opened, it setContentView to a layout named flipper, and
-ELSE if starts the intent of going to the activity MainPage.Class

Now, the apps start up fine but the flipper layout loads again and again every two seconds or so in an infinite loop

My activity is the following:

```
public class Tutorial extends MainActivity{

private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
private float lastX;
private Tutorial mContext;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
SharedPreferences prefs = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.flipper);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("yo.laststage", MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {

        class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                try {
                    // right to left swipe
                    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.in_from_left));
                        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.out_to_left));
                        viewFlipper.showNext();
                        return true;
                    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.in_from_right));
                        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.out_to_right));
                        viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                        return true;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return false;
            }
        }


        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();

        Intent i = new Intent(Tutorial.this, MainPage.class);
        this.startActivity(i);

    }
}

}
```

What could be possibly wrong?